# Validation rule on PickList Values

Tags: validation

Hi I am having picklist field having three values "L1 Queue","L2 Queue","L3 Queue"
intially at the time record cration created with L1 Queue.Next time i want to update my record to "L2 Queue" If insted of L2 Ianyone select L3 it will throws an error.

If i upadted record wirh "L2 Queue".next If I am able to update picklist value with "L3 Queue" only not with "L1 Queue".

please suggest anything anything on this .

Comment: Have you already tried writing a validation rule for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text always starts with 'L' and then the number (1,2,3), the following validation code *should* work.  It will throw and error if the prior Level + 1 is not equal to the current Level (after the change).  This would indicate a non-consecutive increment.

```
If( ISCHANGED(field) )
   VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(PRIORVALUE(field),2),1))+1 <> VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(field,2),1))
```